# JBoss EAP 7.1.0 connects using cli but fails using CommandContext or ModelControllerClient

Tags: jboss-eap-7, jboss-cli

I am trying to execute few commands using cli from java code. For this, I am trying to connect to cli but I am unable to connect.

When i connect using jboss.cli.sh -> connect loclahost:9990, it connects.

When I try this from java using CommandContextFactory, it fails.

```
CommandContextFactory.getInstance().newCommandContext().connectController()
```

Exception is:

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
```

I am getting same exception when I am using

`ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)`

Any pointers as what I might be missing?

-Swaraj

Comment: Is the code running on the same machine the server is?

Comment: try this instead:`ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("remote", InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9990); ` and check

Comment: Is your issue resolved,are you able to connect to CLI now?

Comment: No @SwetaPatra, this did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility here could be of the timeout
By default the cli is configured to check for 5 sec(5000ms) if connection is not established in that phase it throws this.
For me it worked when I increased timeout to 20sec(20000)